# Sharp Craig interpolation theorem for $L_{\omega_1 \omega}$

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, model-theory, infinitary-logic

I’d like to know if a sharp version of Craig’s interpolation theorem for $L_{\omega_1 \omega}$ is already known or exists in the literature. By a “sharp” version of this theorem, I mean something like the following statement: if $\phi$ implies $\psi$ then the interpolant $\theta$ is of the same syntactic complexity as $\phi$. For example, if $\phi$ is $\Pi_\alpha$ then $\theta$ is also $\Pi_{\alpha}$.

I am aware of similar “sharp” versions of the Craig interpolation theorem, such as that appearing in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.01588.pdf), but it is not exactly the kind I need. I am pretty certain the “sharp” version above is true, and would be tedius (but not difficult) to prove using a similar proof to the original interpolation theorem. But it also feels to me like something that is known and likely to have been proven before, and that is what I’m curious about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It actually isn't true that the complexity of $\theta$ could be meaningfully bounded in the term of complexities of $\varphi$ and $\psi$.

Let us fix an arbitrary recursive ordinal $\alpha$. Below I sketch a construction of infinitary $\Pi_n$ formulas $\varphi,\psi$, for some finite $n$ such that there are no $\Pi_\alpha$ interpolant for them.

Consider the standard model $\mathbb{N}$ of $\mathsf{PA}$. We fix some $\Delta^1_1$-property $F(X)$ of sets $X\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ that it is not $\boldsymbol\Pi_\alpha$. For example, $F(X)$ could be the property of $X$ to encode an isomorphic copy of $\omega^{\alpha+1}$. Next we fix first-order arithmetical formulas $\varphi'(X,Y)$ and $\psi'(X,Y)$ depending on free unary predicates such that $$F(X)\iff \mathbb{N}\models_2 \exists Y\; \varphi'(X,Y)\iff \mathbb{N}\models_2 \forall Z\; \psi'(X,Z).$$

We put $$\varphi(X,Y) \mathrel{:{=}} \bigwedge \mathsf{Q} \land \forall x \bigvee\limits_{n<\omega} x=S^n(0)\to \varphi'(X,Y)\text{ and}$$
$$\psi(X,Z) \mathrel{:{=}} \bigwedge \mathsf{Q} \land \forall x \bigvee\limits_{n<\omega} x=S^n(0)\to \psi'(X,Z),$$
where $\bigwedge \mathbf{Q}$ is the conjuction of the axioms of Robinson's arithmetic $\mathsf{Q}$.
Observe that any interpolant $\theta(X)$ for this pair of $\varphi(X,Y)$ and $\psi(X,Z)$ should express the property $F(X)$ in $\mathbb{N}$. Thus $\theta(X)$ couldn't be a $\Pi_\alpha$ infinitary formula.

Comment: This looks like a higher-order analog of the (known but not sufficiently well-known) fact in finitary first-order logic that, for any sentence $\theta$, there is a valid implication $\phi\to\psi$ with $\phi$ universal, $\psi$ existential, and all interpolants logically equivalent to $\theta$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Oh, what a nice fact. What's the proof, or where can I find a proof?

Comment: @AlexKruckman Start by Skolemizing $\theta$ to look like a block of existential second-order (function) quantifiers followed by a universal first-order formula. Delete the function quantifiers (so the function variables become new 1st-order function  symbols); what's left is $\phi$. Dually, Herbrandize $\theta$ to universal 2nd-order plus 1st-order existential formula; the existential 1st-order part is $\psi$. The main point is that, before you deleted the 2nd-order quantifiers, both versions were equivalent to $\theta$, and that implies $\theta$ is the only interpolant.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Excellent, thanks!

Comment: I should have said to use different new function symbols in $\phi$ and $\psi$, so they won't appear in an interpolant.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Interesting, didn't knew about that fact. Actually I think that a slight alteration of your proof gives the following. Suppose $\theta$ is a property of models that is $\Delta^1_1$ over $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1\omega}$ matrices. Then there are infinitary $\Pi_2$ formulas $\varphi,\psi$ such that the implication $\varphi\to\lnot \psi$ is provable and any interpolant $\theta'$ for the implication is semantically equivalent to $\theta$. The point is that any $\Sigma^1_1$ over $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1\omega}$-matrix could be Skolemized to a $\Sigma^1_1$ over an infinitary $\Pi_2$-matrix.